# JPA dependency conflicting with Embedded PostgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, windows-8.1

I have a Spring boot application in which Embedded PostgreSQL was used for tests.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.embed</groupId>
   <artifactId>postgresql-embedded</artifactId>
   <version>2.6</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

I am using regular non-embedded PostgreSQL for the application other then tests.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
   <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
   <version>42.1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

I now had to use JPA dependency along with PostgreSQL.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

So far so good but the problem is that as soon as I use the JPA dependency then my tests start to fail. When I remove the JPA dependency then tests start to run again. I have investigated and found that when I don't use the JPA dependency then the embedded PostgreSQL binaries are extracted and run correctly with a message,

```
Extract C:\Users\Dev\.embedpostgresql\postgresql-10.1-2-windows-x64-binaries.zip START
```

After the above message Flyway migration is started But when the JPA dependency is used than the above message is not displayed hence embedded PostgreSQL is not started and Flyway migration is started which eventually fails as there is no server running.

Is this a known issue of JPA dependency with Embedded PostgreSQL? I tried to search for such issue online but could not find anything about it and I am not an expert of Spring boot (yet).

Embedded PostgreSQL Config Class:

```
import com.myproj.microservice.config.DatasourceConfig;
import groovy.util.logging.Slf4j
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigureBefore
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import ru.yandex.qatools.embed.postgresql.EmbeddedPostgres

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct
import javax.annotation.PreDestroy
import java.sql.Connection
import java.sql.DriverManager

@Configuration
@AutoConfigureBefore(DatasourceConfig.class)
@Slf4j
class EmbeddedPostgresConfig {

  private final EmbeddedPostgres postgres = new EmbeddedPostgres()

  @PostConstruct
  void startAndSetupEmbeddedPostgresql() {

    log.debug("Starting Embedded PostqreSQL")

    String url = postgres.start('localhost', 1234, 'testDB', 'testUser', 'testUser')

    Connection conn = null
    try {
      // TODO from db init script?
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url)
      conn.createStatement().execute("""CREATE SCHEMA "myDB" AUTHORIZATION "testUser";""")
      conn.createStatement().execute("""GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA "myDB" TO "testUser";""")
    } finally {
      conn?.close()
    }
  }

  @PreDestroy
  void stopEmbeddedPostgresql() {
    postgres.stop()
  }

}
```

Comment: @M.Deinum Who said MongoDB has anything to do with Embedded PostGres. I just mentioned that project was earlier using MongoDB and I migrated it to use PostgreSQL and I then had to use JPA. In all above explanation have I said one time that MongoDB is causing this or do this question has MongoDB in its tag?

Comment: That is what you hinted at in your question *"The application was using MongoDB which I needed to replace with regular non-Embedded PostgreSQL."*. So not sure why that led to replacing the embedded postgres, that shouldn't matter. You still should be able to use the embedded postgres for testing... If you don't you don't have a server for testing and well testing without a db will not be that much of a test (if you want to do integration tests).

Comment: @M.Deinum Ok I will make it simple. When JPA dependency is used in pom.xml then Embedded PostgreSQL is not started. When I remove JPA dependency then embedded PostgreSQL starts fine.

Comment: Without knowing how things are started it is impossible to know what is happening. I suspect that you are creating the db inside your test, which is too late for Spring Boot to detect it (that is started before that). However that is impossible to tell without the test code.

Comment: @M.Deinum If it helps then I have added the config file for embedded PostgreSQL.

Comment: Is that even being picked up during your test? Also instead of putting it in a configuration I would place this in a `TestConfigurationListener` so that it will run before your test and before everything else instead of making it part of the configuration.

Comment: @M.Deinum This not picked during the tests when there is JPA dependency in pom.xml otherwise it is picked up fine.

Comment: I would strongly suggest, as mentioned before, to place this in a `TestExecutionListener` and not a configuration. If you really want a configuration then figure out why the ordering is borked (or why the deadlock is happening). I was also under the impression that you auto configured it before the normal `DataSourceConfig` but apparently you have your own. You also might want to run before the `DataSourceAutoConfiguration` and `HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration`.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thank you for your suggestions. I had partial success using TestExecutionListener. I have called my function `startAndSetupEmbeddedPostgresql()` inside the `prepareTestInstance` and used this annotation on my Test class `@TestExecutionListeners(value = [MyTestListener.class, DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class])`. The embedded PostgreSQL is started fine. Now I have no idea about this listener that which method is called on tests completion or does it have some separate Listener called on Tests complete? So I could stop the database

Comment: The [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/TestExecutionListener.html) answers that question.

Comment: @M.Deinum Nopes. I am not able to find any help with the Javadoc. Again the problem is that every method of `TestExecutionListener` is executed again and again for each test class. So the database is created again for every tests class I have.

Comment: Correct that is the whole point of the `TestExecutionListener`. If you want to start it once for the whole suite (I assumed you wanted to start it per test or per test class) it will be hard to detect when to stop it.

Comment: @M.Deinum Any idea how it can be started for the whole suite?

Comment: Add a check in the listener if it has been started. I generally use an `AtomicBoolean` which I toggle after starting the container and check in each call of the `prepareTestInstance` (if false start and toggle else do nothing).

Comment: @M.Deinum I have used AtomicBoolean and it worked fine. But yes the problem is that how to determine when it is stopped.